# Are there any natural thermosetting polymers?

Tags: polymers

Is eggwhite a natural thermoset?
A thermoset is a material that is usually liquid, but it solidifies upon heat. Once it's set, trying to melt it by heating it will only solidify it further until it decomposes, chars, burns, and decays. Isn't that what eggwhite is? Does hardening of the egg involve cross-linking of the polymers of the eggwhite?
Cellulose is a natural polymer, but I don't think it's thermosetting. The same thing applies to polymers that make up the human body.

Comment: If you ask wether eggwhite is a thermoset, one wonders what your definition of a thermoset is.

Comment: You need to recheck your definition of thermoset Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

**Thermosets Directly from RRMs: Vegetable Oil Derivatives and Natural Rubber**

*This is a long answer... I couldnt find lesser words to express this*

It may seem strange to refer to coatings based on drying oils as thermosets. Nevertheless, they fit the definition since they undergo chemical cross-linking during the curing process. Drying oils consist of triglycerides containing high levels of polyunsaturated fatty acids, such as linoleic and linolenic acid. Typical polyunsaturated fatty acids contain one (eg. linoleic acid) or two (eg. linolenic acid) “bis-allylic” methylene groups, marked clearly in the red ovals. This bis-allylic position is very susceptible to oxidation by molecular oxygen in air (a process known as “autoxidation”), which leads to formation of hydroperoxides and, ultimately, bond formation between different triglyceride molecules. A hard film is formed when sufficient cross-linking bond formation has occurred. Metal catalysts can dramatically accelerate the rate of curing. Properly formulated drying oils make excellent protective coatings (paints and stains) and durable flooring.

[image]

Alkyd resins are related technology, usually formulated as mixtures of renewable and petroleum-derived ingredients. While processes and compositions vary considerably, a typical alkyd resin is prepared by cooking at elevated temperature (>2000C) a mixture of polyunsaturated triglyceride, a polyhydric alcohol (a molecule with three or more hydroxyl groups) and a dicarboxylic acid (usually phthalic acid or anhydride) until a product of the desired viscosity is obtained. As with drying oils, alkyd resin films cure in the presence of atmospheric oxygen and can be formulated to make durable paints, varnishes, and coatings for electrical equipment. At present, phthalic acid is a petroleum-derived raw material, so about 70% of a typical alkyd resin is renewable.

[image]

The carbon-carbon double bonds in polyunsaturated natural oils can also be converted into reactive epoxy groups using epoxidizing reagents, such as peroxyacids, hydrogen peroxide or hydroperoxides with catalysts, and even certain enzymes. Academic publications and patents have described both properties and applications of epoxidized natural oils with much of the work focusing on materials from linseed and soybean oils. Epoxidized linseed and soybean oils are available commercially for applications such as coating. Acrylate-functionalized derivatives of epoxidized soybean oils are also available; they are made through addition of acrylic acid to the epoxy groups for applications such as printing inks.

[image]

Finally, natural rubber should be included in any discussion of thermosets derived directly from renewable materials. Natural rubber is polyisoprene with 100% of the carbon-carbon double bonds in the cis-configuration. The combination of C-C double bonds with allylic C-H bonds makes polyisoprene very susceptible to cross-linking by free radical reactions such as the vulcanization process, which involves a complex mixture of reactants including elemental sulfur. With proper formulation, cross-linked natural rubber can form extremely tough, resilient materials, as exemplified by tires.

[image]

It is evident that excellent protective coatings can be formulated from natural oils (eg. linseed and soybean oil) and chemically modified natural oils (alkyds and epoxidized oils). Attempts to formulate high performance thermoset materials based on natural oils as the only cross-linking agent have met with less success; although there is ample literature on the subject, the technology has provided few commercial products. This is not surprising since the cross-link density achievable with natural oils is too low to provide properties necessary for true structural applications. In the next post, we will discuss how renewable materials can be applied to high performance thermoset polymers.

Comment: Could you share the image sources? they are too small..

Comment: @Safdar I made them myself using chemspider draw. I have deleted those...

Comment: The text is unreadable

Comment: I will re-edit it later. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: you meant 200°C not 2000°C right?